# The property 'docs' cannot be unconditionally accessed because received can be 'null' Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

After migrate to null-safety showing this error. What should I do now?

```
  Widget chatMessages() {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: messageStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70, top: 16),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                  reverse: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                    return chatMessageTitle(
                        ds["message"], myUserName == ds["sendBy"]);
                  })
              : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        });
  }
```

After adding null check (!) showing this error **<the getter 'docs' is not defined for the type of object>**

```
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              reverse: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
```

Comment: Hi! what type is the `snapshot.data`? can you provide it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to cast `snapshot.data` to its type. Suppose the type is `QuerySnapshot` (change this with the actual type of `snapshot.data`).

```
(snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs.length
```

Instead of typecasting at all locations, we can specify the type of `stream` in the `StreamBuilder`.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  ...
);
```

Now `snapshot.data` is inferred as `QuerySnapshot` and no typecast is required.

```
snapshot.data!.docs.length
```

Answer (score 8):

I have solved mine by adding StreamBuilder and builder(context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot).

```
 Widget chatMessages() {
     return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: messageStream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
       return snapshot.hasData
          ? ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70, top: 16),
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              reverse: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                return chatMessageTitle(
                    ds["message"], myUserName == ds["sendBy"]);
              })
          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

There are a few solutions:

- Provide a type to your `StreamBuilder`:

  ```dart
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> (...)
  ```
- Provide a type to the second parameter of your `builder`:

  ```dart
  builder: (context, QuerySnapshot snapshot)
  ```
- Use `as` to downcast:

  ```dart
  (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs['key']
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Add error and connection state checks like this:

```dart
      Widget chatMessages() {
        return StreamBuilder(
            stream: messageStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Something went wrong');
                }
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Text("Loading");
                }
              return ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70, top: 16),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                  reverse: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                    return chatMessageTitle(
                    ds["message"], myUserName == ds["sendBy"]);
                    });
              });
        }
```