# The property 'docs' can't be unconditionally accessed because the reciever can be 'null'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

When I use this code:

```
return FutureBuilder(
  future: searchResultsFuture,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return cargandoCircular();
    }

    List<UserResult> searchResults = [];
    snapshot.data.docs.forEach((doc) {
      User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
      UserResult searchResult = UserResult(user);
      searchResults.add(searchResult);
    });
 return ListView(
      children: searchResults,
    );
```

I get the error:

```
The property 'docs' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').
```

Adding the null check doesn't solve anything, also everything is declared in a `User` class on another dart file, like this:

```
class User {
final String id;
final String username;
final String email;
final String photoUrl;
final String displayName;
final String bio;

User(
  {required this.id,
  required this.username,
  required this.email,
  required this.photoUrl,
  required this.displayName,
  required this.bio});

factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
return User(
  id: doc['id'],
  email: doc['email'],
  username: doc['username'],
  photoUrl: doc['photoUrl'],
  displayName: doc['displayName'],
  bio: doc['bio'],
);}}
```

Comment: add a ! to snapshot.data.docs.forEach((doc): snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc)

Comment: I clarified in the question that adding the null check didn't solve anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The property 'docs' cannot be unconditionally accessed because received can be 'null' Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66670247/the-property-docs-cannot-be-unconditionally-accessed-because-received-can-be)

Comment: I added the type <QuerySnapshot> to the FutureBuilder, and the ? on snapshot.data, and it solves the error in vs code but it doesn't do anything on the app.

Answer (score 1):

access it using this:

```
snapshot.data?.docs
```

since the data from snapshot can be null and that is why we check in future builder for whether `snapshot.hasData` is true or not.

Comment: When I add the ? it throws this error: The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'docs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'.

Comment: Try snapshot?.data.docs